# Segmentation Fault with basic Boost Usage in C++

Tags: python, c++, boost

I have a very basic C++ program where the end goal will be to create a function that returns a Python tuple.  I've stripped it down these minimal lines:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <boost/python.hpp>
#include <boost/tuple/tuple.hpp>

int main(){
    Py_Initialize(); // initialize the python module
    boost::python::list test_list;
    boost::python::tuple test = boost::python::tuple(test_list);
    return 1;  
}
```

However, on the line:

```
boost::python::tuple test = boost::python::tuple(test_list);
```

I end up consistently getting:

```
Segmentation fault: 11
```

I'm using Mac OS X 10.9.1 and Boost 1.55.  Any clarity would be greatly appreciated.

Here's the crash report:

```
Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000018

VM Regions Near 0x18:
--> 
    __TEXT                 000000010bf76000-000000010bf78000 [    8K] r-x/rwx SM=COW     /Users/USER/*/*.out

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   org.python.python               0x000000010c1f4f40 PyObject_Call + 51
1   org.python.python               0x000000010c1f5101 0x10c1eb000 + 41217
2   org.python.python               0x000000010c1f508f PyObject_CallFunction + 187
3   libboost_python.dylib           0x000000010bf8a282 boost::python::detail::tuple_base::tuple_base(boost::python::api::object const&) + 34 (tuple.cpp:13)
4   a.out                           0x000000010bf77885 boost::python::tuple::tuple<boost::python::list>(boost::python::list const&) + 53 (tuple.hpp:41)
5   a.out                           0x000000010bf777dd boost::python::tuple::tuple<boost::python::list>(boost::python::list const&) + 29 (tuple.hpp:42)
6   a.out                           0x000000010bf77431 main + 49 (camera_hello_world.cpp:8)
7   libdyld.dylib                   0x00007fff8ead25fd start + 1

Thread 0 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
  rax: 0x000000010c2f0328  rbx: 0x000000010c4f6050  rcx: 0x0000000000000000  rdx: 0x0000000000000000
  rdi: 0x000000010c2efb30  rsi: 0x000000010c4f6050  rbp: 0x00007fff53c899d0  rsp: 0x00007fff53c899a0
   r8: 0x0000000000000000   r9: 0x0800000000000100  r10: 0x00007fff8ed8e83f  r11: 0x00007fff825ec980
  r12: 0x000000010c2efb30  r13: 0x000000010c2360c7  r14: 0x000000010c31c2a0  r15: 0x000000010c4f6050
  rip: 0x000000010c1f4f40  rfl: 0x0000000000010202  cr2: 0x0000000000000018
```

Comment: what's the callstack with gdb?

Comment: Process 15008 stopped
* thread #1: tid = 0x43e2a, 0x0000000100268f40 Python`PyObject_Call + 51, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread, stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x18)
    frame #0: 0x0000000100268f40 Python`PyObject_Call + 51

Comment: Python`PyObject_Call + 51:
-> 0x100268f40:  movl   24(%rcx), %eax
   0x100268f43:  incl   %eax
   0x100268f45:  movl   %eax, 24(%rcx)
   0x100268f48:  leaq   1067125(%rip), %rcx       ; _Py_CheckRecursionLimit

Comment: Put those comments into the question itself by editing the question.

Comment: This reads suspiciously like building against a different version of python than you're running against. What's your compile line look like, and where's your python?

Comment: Thanks @Petesh, I think you might be right.  I have references to Python 2.7.6 through homebrew, but I'm running python2.7.5.  Let me take a look at that for a moment.

Answer (score 4):

Thank you all for the help.  The problem ended up being inconsistencies between the versions of the python libraries I was compiling the program with compared to the version of python on my PATH.